# volatile unsigned __int64 with Visual Studio 2005 behaves strangely

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, 64-bit, volatile

I have a server, which uses a global variable to store the next available unique ID.

Originally, this was defined as `unsigned long g_nextUniqueId volatile;` I'm changing all IDs to be 64-bit integers, so this line was changed to `unsigned __int64 g_nextUniqueId volatile;`

There are only two pieces of code that directly access this variable.

The first is to populate it when the server starts, it's very simple, it just runs a SQL query, retrieves a value and stores it into a `unsigned __int64 lastId`, and then there's a statement to store it in the global, `g_nextUniqueId = 1 + lastId;`.

The other is a function to retrieve and consume the next available ID. This is a one line function, `return (unsigned __int64)InterlockedIncrement64((LONGLONG*)&g_nextUniqueId);`

The problem seems to be there there are two different `g_nextUniqueId` variables, for lack of better terms, in the initialization function.

When `g_nextUniqueId` is populated, the correct value is written to the wrong address. According to the debugger, `&g_nextUniqueId` is **not** the address the value was written to. If I store `&g_nextUniqueId` in another variable, as a `void*`, the values of `&g_nextUniqueId` and the `void*` are **not** equivalent. The `void*` value is actually the correct address. This only holds true inside this one function; in any other function, the `void*` and `&g_nextUniqueId` are equivalent.

```
void* somePtr = (void*)&g_nextUniqueId;
Output(ToString(somePtr) + " " + ToString(&g_nextUniqueId));
// Output will be something "0x01BAF1D8 0x0012EFA4"
// 0x0012EFA4 is on or near the bottom of the stack, I believe.
```

Later, when I go to retrieve the next available ID, the `g_nextUniqueId` the `InterlockedIncrement64` acts upon will be the correct one, which has a value of 0, since the initial value was written to the wrong address.

Hopefully this makes sense (the problem description, that is).

Why is the `g_nextUniqueId = 1 + lastId;` line writing to the wrong address? If I change the type back to `unsigned long`, the code works correctly.

At the moment, the only solution I can come up with is copying `&g_nextUniqueId` to a `void*` and then casting it back to a `volatile unsigned __int64` and assigning.

Comment: This might seem stupid, but my first hunch is that you need to do a full recompile.

Comment: Initially considered this, but I did one before I started testing and brushed it off. I'll try just in case.

Comment: `unsigned __int64 g_nextUniqueId volatile;` -- this is invalid declaration, you probably meant `volatile unsigned __int64 g_nextUniqueId`

Comment: Could you post copy-n-paste snippets from the actual files (and identify which files they're from) including the declaration(s) used. As you might imagine, this kind of problem is very dependent on precise details.

Comment: In total, there are over 40000 lines of code, and this file alone is over 7000 lines. But recompiling seems to have fixed it; I guess I made changes after the recompile and forgot. Thanks.

Comment: cv-qualifiers apply to the nearest type to the left of the qualifier (or right, if none exists), so either is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to do a full recompile.

This is often the case when you make a change to a type used in multiple translation units.  Sometimes the dependency checker gets confused.